# Finding sorted array index of closest int value

Tags: c#

I want to use a Lookup-table that contains 205887 positive int values. They are sorted from highest to lowest value.
I have a positive int value (int a). If I have that value inside the table, I want to receive the index (int b) of the value.
If that value does not exist inside the table, I want the index of the nearest-lower value.

This process is performance critical so I want it to be as fast as possible.

Is it possible to create an array with 2^31 values but only 205887 being initialized?
If yes, would that result in the table being roughly the same size of the one I described above?
If yes, could I find b by checking the index of this array with value a and add one to it until I find an initialized entry which contains my value b?

I am just a beginner at C# and could not find sufficient information in documents. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi there please read [ask].  SO is not a code writing service so its best for you to post some code you have tried and say where it is going wrong.  The above also looks suspiciously like a homework question to me.  If you don't have a go at solving it how will you learn anything?

Comment: Would O(Log(N)) be fast enough? If so, use binary search.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Use a hash.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486881/get-closest-next-match-in-net-hashtable-or-other-structure

Comment: @jdweng The actual answer to the question you linked starts with `A hashtable is not a good data structure for this,` ... it actually uses a sorted list with binary search.

Comment: Why isn't a hash a good structure?  The best algorithm is a sorted binary tree when execution time is 0(Log(N)).

Comment: @jdweng Because the OP needs the get the index of the item found, or the index of the next lower item if it was not found - this can't be done with a basic hash container which doesn't store the items in sorted order.

Comment: A sorted has is the fastest method.  The standard hash may need some mods.

Comment: I used the suggestion from Jamiec which so far is the fastest solution I could find yet. Sorry my question was technically so poor, I will do better in the future. :) I wont edit this one as it is solved for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I think what you want is `Array.BinarySearch`.

The return value is:

> The index of the specified value in the specified array, if value is found; otherwise, a negative number. If value is not found and value is less than one or more elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value. If value is not found and value is greater than all elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of (the index of the last element plus 1). If this method is called with a non-sorted array, the return value can be incorrect and a negative number could be returned, even if value is present in array.

You need to start with a pre-ordered list.

Simplest demo code:

```
private static int Find(int[] arr, int value)
{       
    var result = Array.BinarySearch(arr,value);
    if(result>=0)
        return arr[result];
    else return arr[~result];
}
```

Note this returns the *next highest number* when there is no exact match, whereas you wanted the *next lowest number*. I suspect you can get around this by just subtracting one from the result when it is negative - but I'm not 100% sure.

```
...
else return arr[(~result)-1]; // Not sure this will always work for you?!
```

Live example using even numbers: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vxqumd

Comment: This worked for me very well. I did align the array rather than the result so I could use BinarySearch like it is intended.